# References for comprehensive guideline for individualized vaccination schedules

Tags: vaccination

For the most developed countries there exists [official vaccination schedules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaccination_schedule) which result from an in depth analysis of the risk-benefit ratio for the general population. I.e. it is (or should be) the best available schedule **statistically for the whole population**. Lots of physicians follow strictly those guidelines.

However considering a particular individual, you can take other variables into account, which may result in a different optimal vaccination schedule. The only information usually taken into account are diseases which result in a clear contraindication for a particular vaccination. However there are more variables with less impact on the schedule but which may relevant to (slightly) optimize the benefit-risk ratio for the individual.

For example if you have a newborn from a familiy with contact to the drug scene should clearly have a hepatitis B vaccination. However in other families there is clearly (almost) no risk that the infant comes into contact with someone having hepatitis B (for example because of the families social environment and because the infant doesn't go to a nursery), the risks of unintended side effects might be larger then the benefits. Then the doctor should explain this to the parents and also point out that the social environment and thus the risk may change if the child is at puberty and that it might be difficult to send the child to vaccination at this age...

Another example would be the FSME vaccination. If a infant lives in a big city you might come to a different recommendation than for a child of a farmer family living in a FSME risky environment.

A further example is the rota virus. In this case the recommendation might be different if the mother is breastfeeding or not.

Also the timing may depend, for example if a infant is raised at home for the first three years, you might consider giving the vaccination a a bit later than for a infant which is in a nursery the whole day since month 2.

So are there any books or papers which discusses those aspects of individualized optimizing the vaccination schedule in a comprehensive way supported by reliable probabilities and reasoning.

Because of different available vaccines and different risks of getting infected, the answer depends on the country. In particular I am interested in Germany. But discussions based on the situation in other European countries or the US may be comparable. Where as the situation in some African countries will be very different (that's not what I want).

Furthermore my interest is mainly focused on the typical vaccinations during childhood and not about travel vaccinations.

Comment: Have you already looked on Google Scholar?